# If the composition is smooth is it true that both maps are smooth?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have two maps $\phi:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m, \psi:\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^k$ and $\psi\circ\phi$ is smooth. Is it true that both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth?

I think the answer is yes by the chain rule. Is this correct?

Comment: If $\psi$ is constant, $\phi$ could be _anything_. (And vice versa.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is false: the world of smooth functions is not so nice. For a counterexample (as Daniel Fischer said) consider the zero function $\psi:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^k$ given by $\psi(x)=0$, a smooth function. The composition $\psi\circ\phi$ is zero and is also smooth *no matter what $\phi$ is*. To complete the counterexample, choose $\phi$ to be your favorite non-smooth function.

In addition, your reasoning about the chain rule doesn't work: you can't apply the chain rule to the composition $\psi\circ\phi$ unless you know both functions are differentiable.